# Windows 7 DHCP flooding server with requests

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, dnsmasq

Am attempting to connect a Windows 7 laptop to a Debian server running **dnsmasq**. The Windows 7 machine doesn't seem to like the DHCP info it's getting as it re-requests it every ~10 seconds.

The log file on the Debian machine is filling up with repeated 'DHCPREQUEST' and 'DHCPACK' messages. Interspersed with these messages are 'DHCPINFORM' about once a minute.

I've tried adding the `DHCP-OPTION=252,"\n"` line as indicated on several sites but this doesn't seem to help as the Windows 7 machine isn't holding onto the address long enough to need this secondary fix. The Windows 7 machine is able to accept/use DHCP addresses from other servers without any problem. The issue is localized to this one machine.

The *dnsmasq.conf* from the server:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.70.10,192.168.70.200,24h

dhcp-option=252,"\n"
```

Clearly I've missed some crucial step but I'm not sure where to look.

---

EDIT:
Win7 keeps the same address but it isn't usable. It refreshes too often to get a usable request through. Other machines (and phones) can't use addresses from this server either.

---

EDIT: Interesting - setting a static IP on this address (on the win7 machine) still doesn't provide a working connection through this wireless interface.

Comment: Does the win7 keep and use the address it gets?  Do other stations accept the ip from DHCP without a problem?  Or is this a one on one situation?  Have you tried tcpdump to look more closely at the packets?  Did you try putting isc-dpchd into debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Windows 7 flooding DHCP server with DHCPINFORM messages - Brielle's Ramblings](http://brielle.sosdg.org/archives/522-Windows-7-flooding-DHCP-server-with-DHCPINFORM-messages.html), what Windows 7 is constantly looking for is proxy configuration information, even though none is configured. To work around that, provide it with a fake blank configuration:

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
dhcp-option=252,"\n"
```

(252 is [Web Proxy Auto-Discovery script URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol#Requirements).)